# Java project not building additional code

Tags: intellij-idea

Intellij not building/compiling classes again. When I stop the project and run it again it also doesn't compile the lines of code I added to my Java files.
Even when I run clean with gradle.
Springboot project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with updateing my configuration with:
[image]